# How to decode MP3 using libmp3lame decoder using ffmpeg command line?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to decode .mp3 file using libmp3lame decoder in ffmpeg, this ffmpeg build contains libmp3lame. Decoded output can be .wav/.raw format.So can anyone help me how to decode this using ffmpeg command line.I'm using windows 8.1 os.

Comment: You don't need libmp3lame to decode MP3 with `ffmpeg`: it has a native MP3 decoder.

Comment: Thanks..I was able to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use LAME directly, since you are relying on the libmp3lame anyways?.. as in

```
LAME.EXE --decode myfile.mp3 myfile.wav
```